# Construct an uninitialized object of a class

Tags: php, class, constructor

A class of mine needs to offer two ways of constructing an instance: the regular way, that is, using the constructor, and via the factory static method. The problem is that to construct an object in the factory method I need to provide some parameters to the constructor, which would lead to unnecessary computations because the result of those computations would end up in the properties of the object (i.e. object variables) but the factory method knows the values those properties should be set to beforehand and can perfectly set them right after object construction.

```
class AClass
{
    public function __construct ($param1, $param2)
    {
        // some computations ending up in $this->_prop etc.
    }

    public static function factory ()
    {
        $obj = new self(); // no way
        $obj->_prop = "predefined value";
    }

    protected $_prop;
}
```

Could there be a way to construct a "blank" object and then set its properties "manually"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but maybe you can define default parameters like so:

```
public function __construct ($param1=null, $param2=null)
{
    if ($param1 === null){
        // probably called by factory,
        // so we don't have to do anything because they will be set
        return;
    }else{
        //some computations ending up in $this->_prop etc.
    }    
}
```

Then you should be able to call your constructor without any parameters.

Depending on whether your predefined values are always the same you could do something like:

```
public function __construct ($param1=DEFINED_VAL1, $param2='some default')
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: Just by their meaning in the context of the class, the constructor parameters cannot be allowed to have defaults..